# Sorting the dropdown labels generate by Bootstrap Table for columns keep open

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, bootstrap-table

We are using bootstrap table js library.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

When we use:

```
data-show-columns="true"
```

we get the below dropdown list.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu show" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem">
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-field="thumbnailUrl" value="0" checked="checked">
            <span>Thumbnail</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-field="type" value="4" checked="checked"> <span>Recipe Type</span></label>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-field="rights" value="5" checked="checked"> <span>Rights</span></label>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-field="contributor" value="6" checked="checked">
            <span>Contributor</span></label>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-field="rating" value="7" checked="checked"> <span>Rating</span></label>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-field="starRatings" value="8" checked="checked"> <span>Star</span></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

We need to sort this dropdown in alphabetic order along with checkbox state.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am not sure how to start. Do I need to loop through all the menuitem and store the label input and test in an array and sort them and then regenerate the list again.

Comment: Maybe if you build a working example somebody try to help you. ;)